# Nodemon not refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I started learning node js with nodemon.
Istalled everything 1:1 as shown in tutorials, but it doesnt seem to work. When i enter nodemon index.js into the terminal it hosts properly, although any time I make any changes to the code it doesnt change anything in the browser. There is a line saying

> [nodemon] restarting due to changes... "
> Everything seems to work fine with no errors, but changes in browser dont appear.
> In order to see the changes I have to shut nodemon completely and run it again.

using:
Node v19.2.0 (18.12.1 doesnt work either)
nodemon 2.0.20 (1.19.4 doesnt work either)

Has anyone had simmilar issiues and knows how to fix it?

I tried reinstalling node and nodemone, but it didnt help.
I tried installing it globaly or as dev dependency and it doesnt work in any case.
Using different terminals doesnt change anything.

Comment: Did you check the nodemon.json file?

Comment: nodejs have built-in watcher. try node --watch index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out nodemon doesnt want to work when run in windows powershell. I changed it to cmd in VSCode and everything works fine.